# How to check if two strings from different columns are in the same group, when the group is another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

So I have this data frame with three columns: `species` (the names of the species in that row); `syonym` (a synonym species name that occurs in at least one instance of the `species` column in the data frame; and `group`, which is basically groups of occurrences (can have one or more species names). This is a reproducible example of that df:

```
df <- data.frame(
  species = c("Species X","Species A", "Species Z", "Species A", "Species B", "Species C", "Species C", "Species D", "Species D", "Species A", "Species B", "Species E","Species Y","Species W","Species R"),
  synonyms = c("Species Y","Species B", "no_synonym", "Species B", "Species A", "Species E", "Species E", "no_synonym", "no_synonym", "Species B", "Species A", "Species C","Species X","Species R","Species W"),
  groups = c("G1","G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G4", "G5","G6","G7","G8")
)
```

I am trying to create a new column with "yes" or "no" that checks whether a specific group has two synonym species names. For instance, group "G1" has Species A and Species B, so it would be "yes", because "G1" has both Species A and Species B as instances in the `species` column, and they are synonyms of each other. Species Z, although it is in "G1", has no synonyms so it should be "no". Species X has a synonym in the df (the same for Species Y, they have each other), but it doesn't have any row with its synonym in the `species` column in its group, "G1".
"G2" would be "no" because even though Species E is a synonym of Species C, "G2" doesn't have instances of both Species E and Species C in the `species` column.
The species that have "no_synonym" would also be "no".

Basically this would be the output:

```
df <- data.frame(
  species = c("Species X","Species A", "Species Z", "Species A", "Species B", "Species C", "Species C", "Species D", "Species D", "Species A", "Species B", "Species E","Species Y","Species W","Species R"),
  synonyms = c("Species Y","Species B", "no_synonym", "Species B", "Species A", "Species E", "Species E", "no_synonym", "no_synonym", "Species B", "Species A", "Species C","Species X","Species R","Species W"),
  groups = c("G1","G1", "G1", "G1", "G1", "G2", "G2", "G3", "G3", "G1", "G4", "G5","G6","G7","G8"),
at_least_two_synonyms_in_group=c("no","yes","no","yes","yes","no","no","no","no","yes","no","no","no","no","no"))
```

I tried using dplyr, but I'm not getting the output I'm expecting, for instance, the first and third rows have "yes", but they should be "no", because even if Species Y is a synonym of Species X and occurs somewhere in the df, it doesn't occur in "G1". Similarly, Species Z doesn't even have a synonym in the df, so it should be "no" as well.

```
df <- df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  mutate(
    at_least_two_synonyms_in_group = ifelse(
      any(synonyms %in% species) & any(species %in% synonyms) & n_distinct(intersect(synonyms, species)) >= 2,
      "yes",
      "no"
    )
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you reduce the logic to just check if `synonyms` is in `species`?

```r
df %>%
  group_by(groups) %>%
  mutate(
    ingroup = if_else(synonyms %in% species, "yes", "no")
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
#      species   synonyms groups at_least_two_synonyms_in_group ingroup
# 1  Species X  Species Y     G1                             no      no
# 2  Species A  Species B     G1                            yes     yes
# 3  Species Z no_synonym     G1                             no      no
# 4  Species A  Species B     G1                            yes     yes
# 5  Species B  Species A     G1                            yes     yes
# 6  Species C  Species E     G2                             no      no
# 7  Species C  Species E     G2                             no      no
# 8  Species D no_synonym     G3                             no      no
# 9  Species D no_synonym     G3                             no      no
# 10 Species A  Species B     G1                            yes     yes
# 11 Species B  Species A     G4                             no      no
# 12 Species E  Species C     G5                             no      no
# 13 Species Y  Species X     G6                             no      no
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried on my original data set but I found that, for example, a species that is the sole member of a group (which has a synonym in the df) will have "yes", but it should have "no". I've udpated my example to include that case

Comment: My code still generates the same as your `at_least_two_synonyms_in_group`, did I miss something in the change?

Comment: BTW, I used `.by=groups`, which requires `dplyr_1.0.0` or newer; if you have an older version than your output would be different. What version are you on?

Comment: I have 1.0.7. I tried the code but the last two rows (the ones I added, Species W and Species R) have "yes" in the new column, and they should be no because the synonyms are not occurring in the same group

Comment: Okay, I'm mistaken ... `.by=` is added in `dplyr_1.1.0` (https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/dplyr-1-1-0-is-coming-soon/#temporary-grouping-with-by), so you don't have it yet. Try my edit, going to the original `group_by(groups)` method.